# Shell Script for Yesterdays Date

Tags: shell

I have tried adding `-d "yesterday"` but I haven't had any luck getting it to work.  Here is what I have for the whole script:

```
#! /bin/bash

saveDir="TJ"
dd=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")
for file in *.csv ; do
    saveName="${saveDir}/TJ ${dd}.csv"
    cut -d',' -f2,14 "$file" > "$saveName"
done
```

how do I get `dd` to output yesterdays date instead of the current date?

**EDIT:** This is what I have now

```
#! /bin/bash

saveDir="TJ"
dd=$(date --date='yesterday' +'%m-%d-%Y')
for file in *.csv ; do
    saveName="${saveDir}/TJ ${dd}.csv"
    cut -d',' -f2,14 "$file" > "$saveName"
done
```

the above is saving the file as `TJ .csv` but I'm not sure what was done incorrectly

Comment: what did you get by -d yesterday ?

Comment: %Y%m%d is a much better long-term format for dates. They sort automatically, year-after-year, month-after-month, AND you can do `<, <=, >, >=` comparisons on them without calling any `date` specific processes. Good luck.

Comment: Note that `--date` is a GNU extension that is only present on Linux boxes.  The "standard" `date` utility is only capable of (1) setting the current time and (2) displaying the current time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you want to use -

```
$ cat test.sh
#!/bin/bash

dd=$(date --date='yesterday' +'%m-%d-%Y')
echo $dd
$ ./test.sh
12-31-2013
```

or you could use

```
$ date -d '1 day ago' +'%m-%d-%Y'
12/31/2013
```

And for tomorrow -

```
$ date -d '1 day' +'%m-%d-%Y'
01/02/2014
```

or

```
$ date --date='tomorrow'
Thu Jan  2 21:25:00 EST 2014
```

Answer (score 1):

Get today's date in seconds since epoch.  Subtract 86400 to get to yesterday.  Then convert yesterday to the string format you want.

```
today=`date +"%s"`

yesterday=`expr $today - 86400`

dd=`date --date="@${yesterday}" +"%m-%d-%Y"`
```

Comment: bare back-ticks in a posting will only highlight the selected section as `you see here`. Select a block of text and use the {} tool at the top left of the input box to display code samples in your answers. Also, `$( cmd )` is the modern method of cmd-substituion. Backticks are listed as deprecated in the 1995 'The New KornShell Command and Programming Language', by Bolsky and Korn. Join the 90's ;-). Good luck to all.

Comment: Since the shell is `/bin/bash` in the question, you can definitely use `$(($today - 86400))` instead of `expr`; you can even drop the `$` though personally, I wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
yday=$(date --date yesterday "+%d-%m-%Y")
echo $yday
```

And If you works in Linux

```
yday=$(date -d "-1 days" +"%d-%m-%Y")
echo $yday
```

Comment: Both formulations work with GNU `date` (which is the default `date` command on Linux, but not necessarily anywhere else).

Answer (score 0):

I tried `date -d "yesterday" +%m-%d-%Y` on my Linux, it worked fine.

If you are on unix platform, you cannot use `-d`,
you can get yesterday's date using perl, this is how I do using `perl`

```
dd=$(perl -e '($a,$b,$c,$day,$mon,$year,$d,$e,$f) = localtime(time-86400);printf "%02d-%02d-%4d",$day, $mon+1, $year+1900')
echo $dd
01-01-2014
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 NewDate=`date +"%A %d %B %Y" --date="-1 day"`
 echo $NewDate

 this will give your yesterday's date (-1)
 This will give you tomorrow's date (+1)
 even you can check for any values like (+/-) days
```